# Checking that we are currently inside catch block (without std::current_exception)

Tags: c++, exception

I have a function that returns debug information about the current exception using rethrow trick.  Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

const char *what()
{
    try                             { throw; }
    catch (int)                     { return "int"; }
    catch (const char *e)           { return e; }
    catch (const std::exception &e) { return e.what(); }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw "hello";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "calling what with active exception" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cerr << "calling what without active exception" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << what() << std::endl;
}
```

However program [terminates](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/097e3147b0537cb0) if this function is called outside of catch block (if there is no active exception), but I want it just to return nullptr in this case. I can use [`std::current_exception`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d74797cd2b33757) function to detect if there is an active exception.

```
const char *what()
{
    if (!std::current_exception())  { return nullptr; }    
    // ...
}
```

However calling `std::current_exception` may involve allocating in heap and exception copying which I don't want. Is there a way to check if we are currently inside catch block without using `std::current_exception`?

Comment: Why don't you just make your exception types return something useful from `what()`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception ?

Comment: See bullet #8 at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate.

Comment: You can start your `what` function by calling `std::nested_exception::nested_ptr()`. If the returned value is `nullptr` then there is no exception, and you can simply return `nullptr`. Otherwise, continue with what you have already implemented.

Comment: @Borgleader `uncaught_exceptions` is used in the stack unwinding process.  When the exception is caught in a `catch` block, it returns zero.

Comment: I didn't understand , why you need to call what() outside catch statement, where the what() function throws an exception which obviously will result in std::terminate() being called.